# Spellcheck photoshop document keywords

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-management, metadata

Sometimes when I open the `File Info` and I enter the title, description  and keywords I misspell some words. Is there any way to use spellcheck in `File Info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution it would be to copy the Title/Description/Keywords to an editor and use the Spell-Check

- Microsoft Word
- [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [Aspell](http://aspell.net/win32/) plugin